# What algorithm does the disk management system have in Ubuntu? (HDD)

Tags: lts, 21.04

I want to know what algorithm does the disk management system have in Ubuntu (HDD), I mean if it is SSF, C-Scan, Scan etc.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I’m misunderstanding the question, but I believe you’re asking about disk *scheduling* algorithms. If this is correct, then the following answer addresses the question.

---

Ubuntu uses [multi-queue I/O schedulers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/IOSchedulers) for versions 19.10 to current. BFQ (Budget Fair Queueing) is the default scheduler for hard drives and solid state disks.

Other options include:

- kyber
- none
- mq-deadline

You can check which scheduler Ubuntu is using for a given block device like this:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

The Ubuntu Wiki link above outlines how you can adjust your settings for each block device if you would like to try something different

Comment: Thx @matigo, sorry for the bad explaining, yes i think, i was meaning the I/O for disk, like how the reader head read the disk (hdd) if read by sector, FCFS, etc